# Get placeholder values on firebase onWrite database function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement a counter function to add up number of likes on a post, here is the code (taken from the firebase counter function example) I have modified it a little, how do I get the placeholder values specificed in the database ref (cid, coid)?

```
exports.countCommentChange = functions.database.ref('/clipComments/{cid}/{coid}').onWrite(event => {

    const db = admin.database();
    const clipRef = db.ref(`/clips/${cid}`); // <- how do I get CID?

    const countRef = clipRef.child('comments');

    return countRef.transaction(current => {
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) + 1;
        }
        else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) - 1;
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Counter updated.');
    });
});
```

my database structure is as follows:

```
clips: {
    clipId: {
        name: "my awesome clip",
        likes: 0,
        comments: 0
    }
},
clipComments: {
    clipId:
    {
        commentTimestamp: {
           comment: "awesome video!"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You `console.log` your `event` from the `onWrite` listener, You will able to see the whole data stored in this object at the dashboard console.

You should notice a object at the beginning named `params`. This Object will store all placeholder variables in the exported function.

In Your case, You should be able to access your placeholder with `event.params.cid`.

I hope it helps!